# How Interface can refer to object where no interface is implemented?

Tags: java, interface

I created a connection to a mysql database. Below is my code

```
 package org;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DatabaseConn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Loading driver...");

        try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
    }

        try {
                String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys";
                String username = "root";
                String password = "root";

                Connection Con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
                Statement stmnt = Con.createStatement();
                String SQL = "SELECT * FROM sys_config";
                ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery( SQL );

                System.out.println("Records:"+rs);


    }   catch (SQLException err) {
                System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }

    }
}
```

My Understanding towards Interface implementation on classes says, Interface type reference to an object of class that implements Interface.

But when I investigated below code snippet used in above code..

```
Connection Con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
```

DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password) returns a reference(of type Connection) to a object but no interface is implemented in class DriverManager. Can anyone clear my this doubt ..? Or I missed out anything ?

Same thing am not able to get with below code snippet

```
Statement SQL = Con.createStatement();
```

Con.createStatement() should return a reference to a object that implements Statement interface. But this Connection interface is implemented by ConnectionImpl class where implementation is present like below

```
public class ConnectionImpl
  extends ConnectionPropertiesImpl
  implements Connection {

    public Statement createStatement()
        throws SQLException
      {
        return createStatement(1003, 1007);
      }

      public Statement createStatement(int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency)
        throws SQLException
      {
        checkClosed();

        StatementImpl stmt = new StatementImpl(this, this.database);
        stmt.setResultSetType(resultSetType);
        stmt.setResultSetConcurrency(resultSetConcurrency);

        return stmt;
      }

}
```

Comment: Well, obviously `StatementImpl` is a class that implements `Statement`, and  `createStatement()` returns an instance of that class.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at this bit by bit:

> `DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password)` returns a reference (of type `Connection`) to a object...

This is correct.

> ...but no interface is implemented in class `DriverManager`.

This is also correct.

What your explanation is missing is that `DriverManager.getConnection()` doesn't return a reference to the `DriverManager`. It returns a reference to an object of a *different* class, one that does implement the `Connection` interface.

Let's say for the sake of argument that there is a class called `MySqlConnection`:

```
class MySqlConnection implements Connection {
   ...
}
```

Now, `DriverManager.getConnection()` could well return an instance of this class:

```
class DriverManager {
   public Connection getConnection(...) {
      return new MySqlConnection(...);
   }
}
```

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: I got your point..Could you please tell me that on which class connection is based ..? I mean which class is actually responsible for making connection...From here am checking  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/sql/DriverManager.java#DriverManager.getConnection%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Properties%2Cjava.lang.ClassLoader%29

Comment: @LearnJava: You're likely looking for `com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl`: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java

Answer (score 1):

getConnection and createStatement are [factory methods](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Note that the interface is implemented in the returning object class.

Answer (score 1):

Only the interfaces like `DriverManager`, `Connection` , `Statement` etc. are declared in the JDK , the concrete classes which implement them are there in the corresponding JDBC driver you use. For ex., in your case it is `mysql` jdbc driver added in your class path. So, it is these concrete implementations in the driver jar that knows how to connect to the Database and talk to it. JDK has just defined the specification in the form of interfaces that all the vendor classes should implement. This makes the java code independent of any change in the Database and the corresponding driver.

Comment: I have updated my full code but not able to get records from Table. Its returning "Records:com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@79fc0f2f" only instead of table records..!! Why is it so..?

Comment: You need to iterate through the ResultSet to get each record.